# Symfony 4 and LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle what is the storage of tokens?

Tags: symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am using Symfony 4 with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. My app works perfectly fine, but I am wondering where  **is the storage of tokens** of users. For sure they are not stored in database.

Now I can use `TokenStorageInterface` and call `$tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()` to get logged user by token (the token is sent in headers). Is here a person who could explain to me how does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JWT tokens are not stored anywhere, they're self-contained. The token contains all the information it needs, e.g. user id (or username or whatever you configured) and is signed by your keys, your app therefore knows if it was created by the app or someone else.

Here is how it works:

1. You create a token via the bundle, by default it contains the token type, the token expiration date, your roles and your user identifier (id, username, email, whatever is configured), it's also signed by the public/private keypair or whatever you configured
2. Your client sends a request with the JWT token
3. The bundle checks whether the token is signed by the app and whether it's not expired (and whether you didn't mark the token as invalid)
4. The bundle informs the Symfony security system that the token authenticated you as the user that was stored in the user identifier

That's the simplified flow, that's why JWT tokens were created - you don't need to store them anywhere, they contain all the information and cannot be tampered with.

The only reason you would store JWT tokens is in case you wanted to invalidate them before they expire, then you need to store the token and check whether it's invalidated; and if it is you can mark it as invalid using the events provided in the bundle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one question left - so you mean that those tokens are not stored anywhere. So when user sends the token it is decoded by keypairs or other credentials, yes? And that's why it is not needed to store them?

Comment: It can be decoded by everyone without the keys, if I remember correctly you just split the token by the `.` (dot) character, it should contain three parts, you can `base64_decode` each part and read the output. The first part is header, the second is the data and the last is the signature. The signature is decoded using the keys thus proving that the JWT is created by the app, but decoding of the data can be done even without the keys. Just paste the JWT key to jwt.io and see for yourself the content.